working with the generated files of an angular (17/18) build
In my Angular 17/18 app, when I run ng build for production, the output files in the dist folder are generated, as usual.
I've noticed that there are 2 "chunk-xxx.js" files, and only one of them is called from the index.html file.
So, why only one of them is actually used? Why does the build action generate 2 of those?
Can I run the build action in a way so that there is only one "chunk" file generated?
